# iOS - plist.info becomes blank

Tags: ios, plist

Earlier I was trying to add a network exception in iOS. I was advised to do so in info.plist. While doing that, I found the main entry 'Information Property List'. It was collapsed. I did a right click, and then add new row.

At this point, the whole Key with all its fields went black and all the iOS settings were also set to blank. Now, when I run the app, it comes back and says 'Installation Failed' invalid argument with a big blue button for OK.

[image]
How can I get the old plist back?

Comment: Do you have your project under version control? This is pretty much what it was invented for.

Comment: I did have it under version control. So, I got the file back. However, for good or bad, I end up working with lots of folks who don't use version control. I work as a trainer as well, so I am pretty sure that I will run into this issue (one of my students does this) and there won't be version control to help me out. So, I am just checking if there is anyway to 'reset' or do something to get the default plist back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Open the plist file as "source code". See if the original data is there, but with an extra / duplicate entry that's causing it to be invalid.

Step 2: Create a new project, using the same name and initial parameters as your existing project... Copy the resulting plist file from new project to old project.

Step 3: Change the curriculum of your training to include keeping copies / making backups / using source control (this maybe should be Step 1).

Comment: Yeah, I think I would do this. Yeah. Especially step 3 but I am unable to enforce source control because, sometimes it is simply not available or because it is not allowed due to network considerations or cost or some other reason.